# Adding the progress value inline to Materialize Linear Determinate Preloader

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I am trying to put the progress value, inline with a linear preloader in MaterializeCSS. I've tried a lot of stuff but no success.

```
<!-- Doesn't show any text at all -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="determinate" style="width: 70%">7/10</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Doesn't show any text at all -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>
        <span>7/10</span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Displays the text in new line -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>          
    </div>
    <span class="right">7/10</span>
</div>
```

My intention behind this is to actually show number of steps completed out of the total number of steps (Basically a step progress), but i didn't find any specification in the Material Design Guidelines. And not even text next to progress-bar. Does Material Design Guidelines drops the textual representation of progress ??

Answer (score 3):

Oops !! that was a silly thing to do by using grid. I did try it but made a mistake. Anyways for reference, i am adding the code that worked for me.

```
        <div class="card-panel">
            <div class="row">
                <h5 class="col s10">Lesson Progress</h5>
                <h5 class="col s2 right-align">3/5</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="determinate" style="width: 60%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Attached is the result : 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

**css**

```css
.load-bar {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #fdba2c;
}
.bar {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.bar:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #da4733;
  animation: loading 3s linear infinite;
}
.bar:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #3b78e7;
  animation: loading 3s linear 1s infinite;
}
.bar:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #fdba2c;
  animation: loading 3s linear 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes loading {
    from {left: 50%; width: 0;z-index:100;}
    33.3333% {left: 0; width: 100%;z-index: 10;}
    to {left: 0; width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="load-bar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: send me screenshot How want you output